# Why does Ubuntu choose to put the 2.8.6 version of ffmpeg in their repository?

Tags: ffmpeg, 16.04

The official version of ffmpeg is 3.0.1, shouldn't the newest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS choose 3.0.1 or 3.0?

Comment: There are a million questions on here about "why is newest X not in ubuntu" and there is no single answer. There may be many reasons why some package is not at the latest version in the repositories. The maintainers/uploaders of the package in question would have to answer for a specific package.  In this case ffmpeg 3.0 has not been packaged in debian either, so perhaps would be best to ask them why it isn't there. It's also in universe in Ubuntu and not part of the supported main set of packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [16.04 release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) the [feature freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze) was on February 18, 2016. [FFmpeg 3.0 was released two days prior](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#release_3.0), so I guess there simply was not enough time for the maintainers.